# Command line arguments as variable definition in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to construct a (kind of template/wrapper) script, which is called with some undefined options

```
> the_script.py --foo=23 --bar=42 --narf=fjoord
```

which then creates a variable called `foo=23`, `bar=42`, `narf='fjoord'` inside it.

What's the way to do it? I tried with `getopt`, but it needs a second parameter, so I have to define which options to get and of course, I want to be able to define my variable names via command line. I tried `OptionParser` too, not sure how to deal with undefined options though.

So is the way manually parsing the `sys.argv`, or is there maybe a module out there, which does exactly the same thing?

Comment: python-docopt is a command line argument parsing module. check it out! 
https://github.com/docopt/docopt

Comment: @anandaseelan -- Then all of the commandline arguments need to be known up-front ...

Comment: Just curious -- What do you expect to do with the commandline options once you have them?  Is the syntax always `--foo=23`, or could it be `--foo 23`?

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to have your script depend on its invocation to create variable names that it will reference.

Comment: @mgilson I expect to have well defined syntax, like `--foo=23`.

Comment: @chepner I need this script as a wrapper (a little helper tool for testing some "modules" in our framework, which you normally chain up to process data) and this is the most simple implementation I can imagine. There are lot of modules with different parameters in our framework and at the moment, one have to take a python script, define some preparations and then there is 1 line per "module". So about 100 lines are exactly the same and only that one line is different… and that's why I want to wrap all those preparations in one script and let the user add the parameters and options via cmd line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relatively simple task with `ast.literal_eval` and string splitting -- But only if you have a really well defined syntax.  (e.g. only 1 of `--foo=bar` or `--foo bar` is allowed).

```
import argparse
import ast

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() #allow the creation of known arguments ...

namespace,unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()

def parse_arg(arg):
    k,v = arg.split('=',1)
    try:
        v = ast.literal_eval(v) #evaluate the string as if it was a python literal
    except ValueError:          #if we fail, then we keep it as a string
        pass

    return k.lstrip('-'),v

d = dict(parse_arg(arg) for arg in unparsed)
print(d)
```

I've put the key-value pairs in a dictionary.  If you really want them as global variables, you could do `globals().update(d)` -- **But I would seriously advise against that.**

Comment: `globals().update(d)` is the type of thing that got php into lots of bother

Comment: @gnibbler -- Like I said, I seriously advise against that.  The only way to figure out what variables you have defined in that case is to inspect the `globals()` dictionary anyway ... Might as well just keep a separate dict around and use it.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the possibility of shadowing the builtins.

Comment: @gnibbler -- Yeah, I suppose that's fair.  Although you should find out pretty quickly with a `"sum is not callable"` type of error for most things.

Answer (score 3):

Use this. Maybe you need some string '' brackets some where...

```
>>python yourfunc.py foo=4 abc=5

import sys 
list=sys.argv[1:]
for i in list:
   exec(i)
```