# Creating multiple command line switches and storing to variables

Tags: python-3.x

I have a .py program which I trigger via command line.  I want to add multiple switches when I call the program and then store them to variables.
example of what I'd like to do:

my_program.py /u username /p password /o

In this case, I need the program to store u = "username", p = "password and o = True.

I will add several other switches which may be be used in any order or omitted completely. ie, I may not use the /u switch in some cases and revert to a default value specified by the program.  How do I code this in my_program.py?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line arguments as variable definition in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086594/command-line-arguments-as-variable-definition-in-python)